Ubuntu 22.04 display-manager stops running and freezes
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and every other time, my computer freezes. I can't click on any button.
Before, I used to restart and do my job again. However, I can't anymore because it always happen. I spend 1 hour everyday with this issue on average.
I tried a lot of thing in order to understand why it freezes. I realized that the display-manager stops working but I don't have any idea why.
